# XML Parsing with linq

Tags: xml, linq, c#-3.0

```
<Page>
     <NTrans>
          <Testing testsequence = 1 skew = 3 />
          </Testing>
     </NTrans>
</Page>
```

I want to pull the testsequence and skew using a a var in c#. How would I go about this? Right now I have:

```
var _img = xDoc.Element("Page").Descendants("Testing").Attributes("testsequence").ToList();
```

Which does not work. It says IEnumerable does not contain a definition for ToList

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ToList()` method is an Extension method of IEnumerable. Extension methods were introduced in C# 3.0, so if your tags are correct and you are using C# 3.0, this should be fine.

You may need to import the namespace that contains the `ToList` extension method.

Put this code with the rest of your `using` statements at the top of your code file:

```
using System.Linq
```